# Reference to pointer vs Pass by reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

What is the difference between CodeA and CodeB below?: They are both syntactically correct and it seems both code will be able to modify the original pointer "head".

Please correct me if I'm wrong

Code A: (Pass by reference)

```
NodeType *head = new NodeType();
insertNode(*head, val);
void insertNode(NodeType &head, int val) {}
```

Code B: (Reference to Pointer)

```
NodeType *head = new NodeType();
insertNode(head, val);
void insertNode(NodeType *&head, int val) {}
```

*EDIT*
Would like to add what situation Code A is preferable and vice versa?

Comment: They are not same, in `CodeB` you are able to modify `head` pointer(where it points), that's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it seems both code will be able to modify the original pointer "head"

Wrong. Only code B will be able to modify the `head` pointer. Code A receives the `NodeType` object pointed to by `head`, not the pointer.

> what situation Code A is preferable and vice versa?

Code A is preferable when the function only needs a `NodeType` object.

Code B is preferable when the function needs to modify the pointer value, e.g. changing it to point to another `NodeType` object.

Comment: ok, so Code A received the nodetype object, it is still the same object that is point to by the original "head" pointer right?  A modification to the object from Code A will be able to change the original object point to by Head.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.  

If the above is correct, then both Code A and Code B are able to modify the original object.

Comment: @Mr.Y Correct. The only difference is that in addition to being able to modify the NodeType object, code B will be able to modify the value of the pointer that was passed in.